# Procedure has no parameters and arguments were supplied exception while my stored procedure accepts a parameter

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net

Below is the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Retrieve_Data 
      @noOfRecords INTEGER
AS
BEGIN TRY
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT TOP(@noOfRecords) studentId
    FROM Student;
END TRY    
BEGIN CATCH    
   RETURN -101
END CATCH    
       
RETURN 0
```

Below is the C# code:

```
DataSet ds = null;

try
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.ConectionString))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(storedProcedureName, conn);
            da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter param= new SqlParameter("@noOfRecords", SqlDbType.Int);
            param.Value = 10;
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(param);

            ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "result");

            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }

            return ds;
        }
    }
}
```

While executing the code I am getting a SQL exception:

> Procedure Retrieve_Data has no parameters and arguments were supplied

Comment: Try wrapping your stored procedure with `BEGIN END` like `ALTER PROCEDURE ... BEGIN BEGIN TRY ... RETURN 0 END`

Comment: besides: i don't think you need to close your connection explicit because the `using`block will do this for you!

Comment: One more thing do you connect to correct database? Does your connection string has `|DataDirectory|`?

Answer (score 0):

Change your stored procedure and wrap with `BEGIN ... END`

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Retrieve_Data]
      @noOfRecords INT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN TRY
    SELECT TOP(@noOfRecords) studentId
    FROM Student;
END TRY    
BEGIN CATCH    
   RETURN -101
END CATCH    
RETURN 0; 
END
```

Second thing about ordering table `Student` using `ORDER BY ...`

Comment: The same error? Do you wrap with BEGIN/END? Do you use correct stored procedure in correct schema?

Comment: @user3913587 Try adding `ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Retrieve_Data]` and when call use name with schema

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your stored procedure is incorrect. You need to provide the input parameters inside brackets

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Retrieve_Data]
(
    @noOfRecords INT
)
AS
BEGIN
```

Also you can try to clear your parameters inside the code:

```
if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
   da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Clear();;
   conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Brackets are [fully optional](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189762%28v=sql.110%29.aspx), see examples and syntax